# Generate Scope and Parameter Redefinition

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

Going through "Verilog HDL by Palnitkar", section on "Generate Blocks".
I came across the following statement :

> **Parameter redefinition using ordered or named assignment or a defparam statement can be declared with generate scope. However, a *defparam* statement within a generate scope is allowed to modify the value of a parameter only in the same generate scope or within the hierarchy instantiated within the generate scope**

Doubt;

What really is "generate scope", and what is the author trying to say with the above two statements?

Stuck on this part for a very long time. Kindly help.

Comment: You could always ask the author.  I think this is him: https://www.linkedin.com/in/samirpalnitkar/

Comment: just a suggestion, do not use *defparams*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `defparam` construct is considered outmoded and should replaced with instance based named or ordered overrides as defined in Verilog-2001. This makes the flow of parameter overrides well structured from top instance to bottom. Since `defparam` overides parameters from any hierarchical place, it introduces anomalies that have to be restricted.

```
module down #(parameter PP=2);
  initial $display(PP);
endmodule
module top;
  parameter P = 3;
  down #(.PP(P)) inst(); 
endmodule
```

A generate scope is a block of conditional code (See section *27. Generate constructs* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595))

```
module top;
  parameter P = 3;
  if (P==3) begin
     defparam top.P = 2; // not legal
  end
endmodule
```